# Is it possible to use multiple prefixes for a single snippet in Hypersnip?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With regular VSCode snippet you can trigger a snippet with more than one prefix using:

```
"prefix": ["pf1", "pf2", "pf3"]
"body": "you typed pf1, pf2 or pf3"
```

Trying the same syntax in Hypersnips doesn't seem to work. I've tried inside [] or inside {} or just separating the prexifes with commas:

```
snippet [pf1,pf2,pf3]
snippet {pf1,pf2,pf3}
snippet pf1,pf2,pf3
```

but nothing seems to work. Is it possible in Hypersnips and what is the correct syntax?

Comment: create a regex that matches all your prefixes, you can use capture groups of the prefix regex in the code, just like `lorem3` in emmet

Comment: You could just make the prefix like this: \`pf1|pf2|pf3\` - surround the alternatives with single backticks, that is a regex prefix.